# Recording video with webcam using VideoCapture

Tags: python, video-streaming

I want to record a video with python (using my webcam) and I came across [VideoCapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) which was easy to install on windows. I know there is OpenCV out there, but that was too much for me.

So far I can create every 0.04 seconds a .jpg with this code:

```
from VideoCapture import Device
import time
cam = Device(devnum=0) #uses the first webcame which is found

x = 0
while True:
  cam.saveSnapshot(str(x)+'.jpg', timestamp=3, boldfont=1) #########################
  x += 1
  time.sleep(0.04)
```

0.04 seconds * 25 = 1. So what I am planning to do is an animated gif, that has 25 frames/sec. If somebody of you knows how to produce a real video file like .mp4, I really would prefer the .mp4 rather than .gif. However if thats not possible, the next thing I need to do is, to concatenate all .jpg files (0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg ...) but as you can imagine with increasing recording time I get A LOT of files. So I was wondering if it would be possible to write the .jpg files (the frames) to one .gif file consecutively. If thats not possible in python, how would you concatenate the jpg files to get an animated gif in the end?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV will make it more easy.  You will find more problem in your method.  To use opencv you have to install 1 more package known as `numpy` (numerical python).  It's easy to install.  If you want to install it automatically:

### Install

1. Install pip manually
2. After that go to your `cmd>python folder>Lib>site-packages` and type `pip install numpy` *but for using pip you have to be in internet access.
3. After installation of numpy just type `pip intall opencv`.

Now you can import all the packages. If numpy somehow fails, maunually downlaod numpy 1.8.0 and install it.